# What does the scaladoc mean when it says "All operations are guaranteed to be performed in a single-threaded manner"?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Looking at the scaladoc for [Traversable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable) it says

> All operations are guaranteed to be performed in a single-threaded
>   manner.

Is that just saying "these data structures are thread-safe" or does it imply something more complex/subtle/nuanced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the thread on which the call is invoked is the one that will be used for the entire operation, even it if examines or operates on every element in the collection.

That distinguishes them from the parallel collections which will use potentially all available processors in parallel and thus multiple threads to conclude the collection operation as quickly as possible.

Comment: So why would you seek a "guarantee" that it will be single-threaded?

Comment: So you can reason about its behavior in a multi-threaded environment? So you can decide whether you can protect its integrity with `synchronized`? Scala has mutability and not all its collections are thread-safe. Thus we (programmers) need this information to code correctly.

Comment: Upon reflection I guess this is a very generic interface shared by mutable and immutable collections, one of which is threadsafe and the other isn't, so its not about thread-safety. Oh yes you do point out that if it were something which was a parallel collection then you could not protect an immutable structure by synchronising on it since it may be another parallel thread which does the updates. Got it.

Comment: i updated the answer just to spell out what is being pointed out in the comments here (wont be visible until peer reviewed)